# Not smart enough to fix mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1

Tags: php

I have spent hours trying to follow all the great advice of coders here trying to fix this problem. I KNOW this is a duplicate of 50 other posts, but cannot find any code close enough to mine to fix it. I am new to PHP and have an old eCommerce cart on a site that cannot be updated. Please don't flame me for my ignorance. Can someone give me the exact instructions on how to fix this. Thanks in advance!

I just copied the code directly from the file. I did not add all the @.

## The error:

```
mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/xxx /public_html/vsadmin/inc/mod/text.php on line 18
```

## The code from test.php

```
 <?php
    $cat = @$_GET['cat']; // Current Category ID
    if(trim(@$_GET['cat'])!='') $theid = unstripslashes(@$_GET['cat']);
    if(@$explicitid!='' && is_numeric(@$explicitid))
    $theid=@$explicitid;
    elseif(@$usecategoryname && $theid!=''){
    $sSQL = 'SELECT sectionID FROM sections WHERE '.getlangid('sectionName',256)."='".escape_string($theid)."'";
    $result = mysql_query($sSQL) or print(mysql_error());
    if($rs=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ $catname=$theid; $theid=$rs['sectionID']; }
    mysql_free_result($result);
    }
    $cat = $theid;
    $queryrank="SELECT * from sections WHERE sectionID= '" . $cat . "' ";
    $resultrank=mysql_query($queryrank);
    ?>
    <?php
    while ($sSQL =mysql_fetch_array ($resultrank))//<< line 18
    {
    $text = $sSQL['cattext'];
    $html = $sSQL['cathtml'];
    $optiom = $sSQL['catoption'];
    if($sSQL['catoption']==1) {print "$text ";}
    else print "$html";
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: where you have added the db connection ?

Comment: First of all, stop with all the `@`. You do not want error suppression! Suppressing errors is exactly what makes it impossible for you to figure out what's wrong!

Comment: also which is your line 18..

Comment: [RTFM](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) `For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.` Obviously `$resultrank` is `false` and you have to deal with an error of some sort. As @deceze correctly said, stop using error suppressing. Also stop using `mysql_*` functions (see the red box at the top of the manual pages), use [`mysqli`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)

Comment: Have you followed advice from the duplicates you have obviously found? Like to `mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_eror())`?

Answer (score 0):

The only `mysql_fetch_array` I see in your code is

`while ($sSQL =mysql_fetch_array ($resultrank) )`

So, `$resultrank=mysql_query($queryrank);` must result in `false`.

Ergo, your query `$queryrank="SELECT * from sections WHERE sectionID= '" . $cat . "' ";`
 throws an error.

echo the mysql_error and you know what's wrong.

And, if you can, STOP using mysql-functions, they are depricated. Use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: I cannot update this old shopping cart for the owner. It destroys her cart when I tried to update. I added the error reporting to the script. I'll see what happens. This is a very inactive cart so it may take time. Thanks for trying to help.